# Is there such a thing as a "get bullied by evil cheerleaders" simulator?

Tags: windows, 3d, game, simulation

Call me weird, but it strikes me that it would be *technically* possible for there to now exist a reasonably photo-realistic "bullied by evil cheerleaders" first-person 3D simulator. Perhaps it would not be possible to make due to financial/marketing problems, but technically, nothing would prevent this.

Basically, I'm imagining a minimal "game" without any story/wrapping, where you immediately begin in first-person as a school boy in a typical American school, in a random room/area. Your objective is to get to your locker, open it, put in your books and then walk home, without getting found out by the popular and cruel cheerleaders, who love to tease and bully you. Basically, it's "survival horror" but without any supernatural/jump-scare/unrealistic elements.

The school can be completely empty from all people, and that doesn't have to be explained. (Maybe the boy just accidentally fell asleep in a study room when it was already at the end of the day.) The cheerleaders sometimes walk together and make noises such as giggling in the distant, and you have to avoid them by hiding carefully and stealth-like. Sometimes, they notice you and split up to catch you by taking different paths, etc. They are fast and well-trained, and you are a stereotypical "nerd" who isn't exactly an athlete, and you have to rely on your wits to escape.

It should be *possible* to avoid them entirely and escape safely, but it should be very difficult and require a lot of practicing and many failed attempts. It can naturally have levels of difficulty, where the worst one is called something like: "Doomed to get bullied"

When you get caught by the cheerleaders, it's game over. They quickly run up to you, surround you and start laughing and shouting things such as "neeeeeeerd!", "looooser!", "fatass!", "point-dexter!", etc. You know, the stereotypical things that "cruel cheerleaders" in movies tend to say/do, regardless of how common this really is in reality. Sometimes, they might forcefully strip you naked and make you run home crying, or put makeup on you and have you walk into the teachers' lounge, or kick you while making you oink like a pig, etc. But those "fatalities" obviously spell a lot of extra work.

The main efforts of this simulation/game would be creating the cheerleaders' 3D models, AI and all the animations/voiceacting for when they bully you. Essentially, besides being a genuinely scary psychological horror simulator, that's mostly an excuse to get to "experience" digitally what it would feel like to be bullied by such girls.

No, I don't think it's "morally right". Yes, I was kind of bullied by cheerleaders myself. Yes, I want to re-experience it, over and over, and such a simulation would be the only safe/logical way of doing so. I don't like supernatural/over-the-top horror nonsense with zombies and ghosts and guns and all that stuff. I want this far more realistic scenario which is intriguing and scary precisely because it *does* happen.

It's important that they are not just general bullies, but specifically popular, beautiful, cruel, female ones.

Yes, I know about the old game "Bully". It has nothing to do with this. And neither does Grand Theft Auto or any Japanese anime "slideshow adventure" game. I'm not looking for some kind of "sex simulator". The cheerleaders never get naked and in case they strip the boy you are playing as, those parts are blurred/censored. I'm 99% sure that this doesn't exist, and if it does, it's probably in some very crude form which wouldn't be fun to play...

Imagine if this were something that they put in real money to create as an AAA title. It would be so cool...

Comment: Welcome Bullied!  I have never been nearly speechless after reading a question in our community, but you, my friend, win a big prize by being the first to attain that accomplishment! :)  Unfortunately, this question will need to be closed, because we recommend software that already exists (you are very welcome to modify your question to meet that requirement so it can remain open).  I find myself in the odd position of wanting to better understand: Why do you want re-experience these memories?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I guess it's a very complex psychological thing, but in this case, at least it's only involving virtual/digital "people" inside a fake world, so it doesn't harm others. I hope that it does exist, even if I don't *think* that it does.

Comment: If you will, try editing your question just a little to make it fit our site. After you've done that, I'll read through it again and make any edits necessary to ensure it is really a software recommendation. You can read through our Help system to get good pointers for what is required for a question to be appropriate for our community. Be sure to add in things like OS and price, if applicable. I'm rather busy, but you've piqued my curiosity regarding what you are truly trying to attain. Although not required, feel free to add those details as well.